# Creating pointers inside the heap allocated/ malloced memory

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a chunk of heap allocated memory to which I can assign objects of multiple types using void pointers. However, my intent is to use the first couple of memory addresses for metadata. I assume that these first couple of blocks would be holding addresses referring to the start, end, and amount of free space in the block. As a result, these would have to be pointers. Therefore, I would have to cast my void pointer and in turn dereference that to store another pointer, but I am unsure of the syntax. Is there any document that I could refer to or existing code that would point me in the right direction. I am rather new to the concept of storing metadata, hence my ignorance. Any advice would be very helpful.

I have looked around for resources but have not found any

Comment: Why not create a `struct` or `class` with the data types needed and then simply allocate for one of those? (or better just create an instance and avoid manual allocation altogether)

Comment: One might question why you're doing all of this extremely low-level pointer manipulation in C++.  If all you need is the ability to store a couple of different types, then [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) is your friend. For more messy business, [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) is your friend. Casting `void*` is the sort of thing you see in C code written in the 80s, not C++ code written in 2022.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I was unclear about this in the post but the idea was to have a chunk of memory without any object headers/other such information associated with it, hence the idea of not using a class/struct

Comment: If you really want to create a block of memory containing pointers, you can do `char **my_ptrs = new char*[how_many];` Where `how_many` is a constant for the number of pointers you want. You will then need to handle the casts, but at least a char_type avoids pitfalls of strict aliasing. You can either assign address to existing memory to the pointers or you can allocate storage and assign the starting address to each pointer -- up to you. It will be up to you to `delete` any additional memory allocated and `delete[] my_ptrs;` when done.

Comment: You access each pointer as `my_ptrs[i]` where `0 <= i < how_many`.

Comment: "the idea was to have a chunk of memory without any object headers/other such information associated with it"  c++ is noted for not storing anything but the actual data.  So it isn't clear what you are expecting to avoid.

Comment: Don't use malloc, if you want to create objects in pre-allocated memory use [placement new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new). Casting memory pointers to objects will NOT result in valid (new-ed) objects.

Comment: The bad thing about void* in C++ is that you use ALL type information. I haven't needed any in C++ for over 20 years (except in some cases where I had to interact with legacy code, and even then the cast to a void* is the last thing I do). You also fall into the trap of describing HOW you want to do something, without telling WHAT is is you want to do. Because I suspect that in this case if we understand WHAT you want to do we can give better answers.

Comment: @albercik There *are* no object headers in C++. You're thinking of Java. In C++, the memory for your object is just that: the data in the object, plus a few padding bytes for efficiency (and don't try to outperform the compiler on padding; it knows the computer better than you do). If you use virtual functions, you'll also have a vtable. But that's it.